# using data from a current query

Tags: sql-server, join, subquery

If I run a sql server query that returns the following rows from two separate tables:

```
_____________
 01 | yellow
 01 | red
 02 | green
 02 | purple
```

can I run a sub query in that same query using the values of each row that are returned?

For example, the first row returns 01 and "yellow" and I want to return a third column that gives me a value from a third table based on those two values. I would assume a JOIN could do this, but I don't know how I would do it with two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to JOIN the third table on both columns, similar to this:

```
select a.id, b.color, c.YourCol
from table1 a
inner join table2 b
  on a.id = b.id
inner join table3 c
  on a.id = c.id
  and b.color = c.color
```

Comment: You are awesome! That made things so much easier. Worked like a charm. Thanks!